# Jquery/Pikachoose problem page continusly reloading ie7/ie6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am using pikachoose plugin for slider. But I changed a few code in the plugin to add links to thumbnails, it works perfectly on firefox, chrome. But when i open the page in ie7 or ie6 the reloads indefinitely. here is the code i added in the plugin

```
jQuery("#pikame li").each(function(){
                                var link = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
                                jQuery(this).find('img').wrap("<a></a>");

                                })
                jQuery("#pikame li").each(function(){
                                var link = jQuery(this).find('span a').attr('href');
                                jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href',link);

                                })
```

if i remove thie cod everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem in `wrap("<a></a>")`?  Shouldn't that anchor have an href?